# Is the functionality extend different from doing tap and then include

Tags: ruby

If I initialize an object like this:

```
a = A.new
a.extend(B)
```

Is that different from doing the following?

```
a = A.new.tap do |a|
  include B
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, both are not equivalent.

`a.extend(B)` adds the methods of module `B` only to instance `a`, whereas

```
a = A.new.tap do |a|
  include B
end
```

is equivalent to

```
include B
```

Inside the block of `tap`, the current `self` is `main` and whenever you include a module in `main`, the methods from included module becomes instance methods of `Object` class, as shown below:

```
class A
  def class_meth
    "class meth"
  end
end

module B
  def module_meth
    "module meth"
  end
end
p Object.instance_methods
#=> [:nil?, :===, :=~, :!~,...
a = A.new.tap do |a|
  include B
end
p Object.instance_methods
#=> [:module_meth, :nil?, :===, :=~,...
```

Hence, you feel like the effect is similar to `a.extend(B)`, but it is much more.  **Any new objects of any class will have methods of module `B` in them via the `Object` class.**

```
class C
end

p C.instance_methods
#=> [:module_meth, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~,...

p Hash.instance_methods.grep(/module_meth/)
#=> [:module_meth]

p [].module_meth
#=> "module meth"
```

Comment: actually writing the answer and wrote the exact same thing `Inside the block of tap, the current self is main`... Won't continue writing since you did it already :) +1

Answer (score 0):

`include` and `extend` are *not* the same thing. `include` can only add instance level methods, while extends "includes" far more:

> But there are occasions when you would want to include some methods from a module as class-level methods in a class. This is where the method extend becomes useful.

This is just a high level difference, there's much more differences such as `include` being limited in the scenarios where it can work - you can [read more here](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/48-advanced-modules/lessons/117-included-and-extend).

Comment: it does not answer the question

Answer (score -1):

they are not same

extend is method if Object class
include is method if Module class

so, if you will do

```
object.extend(Module)
```

you will add methods from Module to object, but

```
SomeClass.include(Module)
```

will add methods from Module to instance of SomeClass